# Cannot retrieve the content of CDATA from XML API

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

Have tried parsing XML data using both `simplexml_load_string()` and `new SimpleXMLElement()` in PHP from an XML API, but I'm having issues parsing the `CDATA` content. Using the above function or instance in PHP should also parse `CDATA` as content of a node (either by typecasting it as a `string` from a `SimpleXMLElement` or by using the `LIBXML_NOCDATA` flag), but this is not the case. Instead the data is coming out like `<![CData[2801086]]>` (which took a while to notice as echoing this in the browser is not visible as `Cdata` hides it from rendering)

Here's a snippet containing a job position within the API feed (have trimmed down and removed some content):

```
<position>
  <Id><![CData[2801086]]></Id>
  <url>
  <![CData[http://foo.bar.co.uk/ViewVacancy.aspx?2801086-foo]]>
  </url>
  <JobReference><![CData[VAC-00117]]></JobReference>
  <JobTitle><![CData[Foo Bar]]></JobTitle>
  <County><![CData[Nottinghamshire]]></County>
  <Town><![CData[Nottingham]]></Town>
  <Postcode><![CData[NG11 0EE]]></Postcode>
</position>
```

Comment: CDATA must be written in upper case. The way you have written it, it's not well-formed XML.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Michael. Yeah, I know (have answered this below). Was not written by myself unfortunately, so need to let the developers providing the service know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This consumed many hours so thought I'd post it to save someone else the pain. Both `simplexml_load_string()` and `new SimpleXMLElement()` in PHP require `Cdata` to be capitalized (i.e. `CDATA`), whilst the web browser (Chrome) was happy without it. Note that is might change with different versions and I'm using PHP 7 at the time of writing this. Once capitalised it appeared without the `Cdata` wrappings as expected.

Comment: Was it parsed as HTML by Chrome? HTML is not case sensitive, XML is.

Comment: That explains it. My eyes glazed over it for a while as the browser interpreted it as it should and PHP didn't throw any exceptions.